# Add class on focus change using Redux and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to add a class to a div wrapping an input on focus with Redux and React.

My React component looks like this:

```
import React from 'react'

const Input = ({ value, onChange }) => (
  <div className="">
    <input type="email" onChange={onChange} value={value} />
  </div>
)

export default Input
```

When a user focuses on the input, I want the class `selected` to be added to the div. The component is connected using `react-redux`.

The two ways I've tried so far:

#### Attempt 1

Add an onFocus listener to the input and dispatch an action that adds the inputs focus state into the inputs state , for example:

```
{
  value: '',
  focused: true
}
```

If focused is true, add the class with `className={focused ? 'selected' : ''}`

My concern with this approach is I could get into issues where multiple inputs have `focused: true`. So I'd have to manage that myself and look through the whole input state and reset to false before setting focus on a new input.

#### Atempt 2

Add an onFocus listener to the input and dispatch an action that contains the ID of the focused input and store the ID in the state. This would solve the issue of having to reset all other inputs to false.

My concern with this is I'd have to give every input I wanted this feature on a unique ID (this could possibly use Reacts ID). I'd have to add something like `className={ID === focusedID ? 'selected' : '')`

---

I feel like there must be a better way to achieve this. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If it is only a presentational thing, I think that its a much better solutions to use CSS:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp

Comment: It is only presentational, I can't use CSS for this because CSS can't select an elements parent. I need to add a class to the containing div when the input is selected. Thank you for your reply though :)

Comment: Then I think that the better approach is to treat the whole code as a one component, and handle the states in local. Play with `onBlur` and with `onFocus`. Take a look to the @QoP answer :)

Comment: @QoP solution worked, thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You dont even need Redux for that, just store the "selected" state in the component.

Something like this

```
var InputComp = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
   return {focus: false}
  },
  onFocus : function(){
        this.setState({focus: true})
  },
  onBlur: function(){
      this.setState({focus: false})
  },
  getClass: function(){
      if(this.state.focus === true)
        return "selected";
      else
        return "";
  },
  render: function() {
    var inputClass = this.getClass();
    return <div className={inputClass}><input onBlur={this.onBlur} onFocus={this.onFocus}/></div>
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <InputComp/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/41809/)

Comment: Thank you, this functions perfectly :) I was not aware you could still manage the components state internally. Is this considered bad practice to keep state that isn't part of the redux store?

Comment: no, it's not a bad practice. In fact, it's a good practice because this has nothing to do with the data :-P.

Comment: This has been one of my main hold ups whilst learning Redux. Determining what belongs in the store and what doesn't. It makes sense to me about only storing the applications data, on the other hand you see a lot examples where non application data is stored, such as the status of an AJAX request. I guess you just need to go on a case by case basis. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @jmahony No it is not a bad practice to put UI in the react component state as long it doesn't get awkward, Dan explicitly said that UI could go in redux store or in the React own state. cf : https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1287

Comment: @QoP best way to implement this with multiple elements that need focusing? I have three elements I want to control focus one but since they are all tied to the single state all are activated instead of being focused one by one

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the [:focus](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp) pseudo-selector. You need to add a class to your `div`s, for instance, focusable. If that is done, you need this CSS rule:

```
.focusable:focus {
    /* Your rules for selected */
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is the input is receiving the focus, not the containing div. Thanks for the reply though.